# Detener media player android, al recibir llamadas o que otra aplicacion use el audio

Tags: java, android

Espero haber sido especifico, el detalle es que estoy haciendo un streaming de audio con media player, y quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de saber si otra aplicacion esta usando el audio del telefono, y de ser asi como interrumpo el servicio (el que uso para el streaming).
Tengo la siguiente clase:

```
public class MyServicioRadio extends Service {
int countdown=0;
int countdown1=0;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
public static Boolean bandera;
public MyServicioRadio() {
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Intent recibido");
    stopPlaying();
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    try {
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://s13.myradiostream.com:35446/");
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    showForegroundNotification();
    /*if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    } else {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }*/
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    //App.getInstance().cancelPendingRequests(getClass().getSimpleName());
    super.onDestroy();
    stopPlaying();

    bandera=false;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

private void showForegroundNotification() {

    // Se construye la notificación
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Futbol Mania")
            .setContentText("Si Si Si");

// Crear Intent para iniciar una actividad al presionar la notificación
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MenuPrincipal.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

// Poner en primer plano
        startForeground(1, builder.build());

// Acciones de proceso...
    }
    private void stopPlaying() {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Espero haberme explicado

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer [esto](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), 
puede tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando este [link](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada o puesta en espera no se lo tome a mal, 
para mas información consulte el siguiente [enlace](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). 
Saludos

Comment: Para detectar si otra app está usando el canal de audio, mira la documentación https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener.html

Comment: También te podría ser de ayuda esos tips https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/volume-and-earphones.html

Answer (score 2):

Cuando tu app accesa a segundo plano puedes pausar el media player, sobreescribiendo el método `onPause()` :

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause{
      super.onPause();
      mediaplayer.pause();
   }
```

Este metodo se ejecuta en tu aplicación al activarse otra aplicación o en este caso cuando recibes una llamada telefonica.

Comment: Es decir, creo un metodo OnPause dentro del servicio?

Comment: Si es una Activity, el método onPause() lo puedes agregar tal y como esta en la respuesta, dentro de este método, la instancia de tu media player debe llamar pause();

Comment: Acabo de agregar la clase del servicio, el reproductor se encuentra dentro de un servicio, como podria pausar el servicio o detener el servicio cuando otra aplicacion que precisa del audio se ejecute?

Comment: Podrías agregar tu código para saber especificamente que realizas, me parece que no estas en una activity

Comment: Ya lo hice, espero me puedas orientar amigo :)

Comment: ohhh veo que es en realidad un servicio y un servicio se ejecuta en background!, permiteme revisar una opción...